Scopes and middleware
When registering services, one can optionally wrap these in additional middleware.
However, the only way I found to do so in separate and then aggregate was using the .scope function.
I particularly want to be able to give different scopes different combinations of middleware but I dont actually want to separate the scopes by a prefix.
mod auth;
mod info;

use crate::auth::{api_key::api_key_middleware, bearer::jwt_middleware};
use actix_web::web::{scope, ServiceConfig};
use actix_web_lab::middleware::from_fn;

pub fn mount(actix_config: &mut ServiceConfig) {
    let public = scope("").service(info::info);

    let with_key = scope("")
        .wrap(from_fn(api_key_middleware))
        .service(auth::login)
        .service(auth::register);

    let with_key_and_jwt = scope("")
        .wrap(from_fn(api_key_middleware))
        .wrap(from_fn(jwt_middleware))
        .service(auth::check);

    actix_config
        .service(public)
        .service(with_key)
        .service(with_key_and_jwt);
}

Firstly, this does not work because there cant be multiple scope("") calls, this will collide and routing of requests wont be made properly. Additionally, I dont want to create custom scopes like  scope("auth") or  scope("jwt").
Is there a way to do so?
Tried scoping with empty strings but it is a) ugly and b) doesnt work since scopes collide and requests wont be properly routed.

"I dont want to create custom scopes" - you will need them to selectively apply middleware to routes.

@kmdreko yes that is a way but dont want that either. Thanks though.

This is issue #414, and it's still open, so it seems there isn't a good solution.
